"Type cannot be deserialized" from a managed package
From a managed package I'm trying to invoke a local batch class in an org with no namespace, but get the error "Type cannot be deserialized".
System.Type t = System.Type.forName('','BatchClassName');
Database.executebatch((Database.Batchable<sObject>)JSON.deserialize('{}',t));

I'm passing an empty string for the namespace parameter. Any idea what I'm missing? Thank you!

Is the class you're trying to instantiate marked global? Does the class have either no constructors or a default (zero-arg) constructor that is also global?

Hey @sfdcfox yes, the class is marked global and has no constructors

I tried adding a default constructor also marked as global and still get the same error

Depending on the batch class's API version, you may need to provide the @JsonAccess annotation.
Since you are not defining any property values, have you considered providing a global default constructor (or no constructors at all) for the batch and calling Type.newInstance() instead of using deserialization?
Note that JSON deserialization does not require any constructor access since it does not actually call any constructor on the class.
As per comments, the subscriber class must itself be global too, so the managed package can see it.

thank you for this answer! Type.newInstance() instead of deserialization worked
